# "missing input response" error recaptcha v3

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

I'm creating a form to send emails with the recaptcha. Everything was working perfectly, but I noticed that the recaptcha v3 only lasted 3 minutes and needed to reset. From there it started to give a "missing-input-response" error.

index.php

```
<script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
         document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value=token;
      }); 
  });
  </script>

  <script>
    var callback = function() {
      grecaptcha.render('id-of-render-element', {
         'sitekey': 'key',
         'expired-callback': expCallback
       });
   };
   var expCallback = function() {
      alert("Your recatpcha has expired, please verify again ...");
      setInterval(function(){ grecaptcha.reset(); }, 5 * 60 * 1000 ); 
   };
  </script>

 <div id="id-of-render-element"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=callback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

class captcha

```
<?php

    class Captcha{

    public function getCaptcha($SecretKey){

        $Resposta = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=key&response={$SecretKey}");
        $Retorno = json_decode($Resposta);
        return $Retorno;
    }

     public function returnCaptcha(){
         echo "entrou calss_captcha";
  $EnviaMail = False;
  $ObjCaptcha = new Captcha();
  $Retorno=$ObjCaptcha->getCaptcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
  var_dump($Retorno);
  if($Retorno->success == true && $Retorno->score > 0.5){
      $EnviaMail = True;
  }else{
      $EnviaMail = False;
  }
  return $EnviaMail;
    }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Is your site having SSL?

Comment: No, i dont have ssl on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the user comment working for Version 2. You need to specify additional parameters to the file_get_contents function call and If your site has SSL then setting the context options.

```
class Captcha{        
    public function getCaptcha($SecretKey){
        if($SecretKey){
            // Input data
            $secret = 'SECRET_KEY';
            $response = $SecretKey;
            $remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

            $post_data = http_build_query(
                array(
                    'secret' => $secret,
                    'response' => $response,
                    'remoteip' => $remoteip
                )
            );
            $options=array(
                // If site has SSL then
                'ssl'=>array(
                    // In my case its /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
                    'cafile'            => '/path/to/cacert.pem',
                    'verify_peer'       => true,
                    'verify_peer_name'  => true,
                ),
                'http' =>array(
                        'method'  => 'POST',
                        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'content' => $post_data
                )
            );
            $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
            $Resposta = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
            $Retorno = json_decode($Resposta);
            return $Retorno;
        }
    }
    public function returnCaptcha(){
        echo "entrou calss_captcha";
        $EnviaMail = False;
        $ObjCaptcha = new Captcha();
        $Retorno=$ObjCaptcha->getCaptcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        var_dump($Retorno);
        if($Retorno->success == true && $Retorno->score > 0.5){
            $EnviaMail = True;
        }else{
            $EnviaMail = False;
        }
        return $EnviaMail;
    }
}
```

Comment: My website does not have the SSL certificate, can I solve the problem without the SSL certificate?

Comment: No issue u can, just remove ssl from array

Comment: I did it and now im getting a new error "error for site owner: invalid key type" on div. Im using Recaptcha v3, i dont need a div for recaptcha for recaptcha right?

Comment: have you added your website(domain i.e. http:www.xyz.com) on google captcha dashboard ? You need to ensure your site is added in the domains section of the google reCAPTCHA page where you generated the API key and save. Then test again

Comment: Yes, I added it to the googlel captcha dashboard. Before I tried to implement this part of the code so the recaptcha did not expire everything was working fine ... I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Are you getting this issue in local host or in production server? check with localhost and 127.0.0.1 to domains in both local and production.

Comment: I am using a production server. On google captcha dashboard im using localhost and my production server domain.

Comment: Then check with other register of captcha . . . This is related to key issue . . .give a try

Comment: Yeah, i swap to recaptcha v2 and now its working. Thank you.

Comment: If my answer is worked in v2 dont forget mark this as answer!